# Presenting several times the same ViewController in a TabBar inside a storyboard

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

Hullo,

I would like to use the same view controller to present various information from within a tabbarcontroller. The number of view controllers will be established programmatically. I found a way to do it by initiating the other viewControllers with their nib, but by using StoryBoarding I have no cue about how to get the nib identifier of a viewController.
Is it possible to use this technique, or Segues give an alternative?

Thanks, Fabrizio